# Installing libstdc++-devel on my CentOS server

Tags: software-installation, libraries

`rpm -qa | grep libstdc++` gives:

```
libstdc++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64
```

However, `find . -name "*libstdc++*"` gives:

```
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libstdc++.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libstdc++.so
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libstdc++.so
./usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
./usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
./usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
./usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyc
./usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyo
```

As you must have noted by now, I need to install libstdc++-devel which is compatible with `libstdc++-4.8.3`.

The problem is, https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B-devel does not show any entry for version `libstdc++-4.8.3`. What are my options now? How do I get libstdc++-devel on this system?

CentOS version as requested: CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Comment: `yum install libstdc++-devel`?

Comment: This probably doesn't matter here, but please state your CentOS version.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sadly I am dealing with a company server that does not allow internet connections.

Comment: Well, that sucks. Does that mean you don't have yum installed and configured?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I do have yum installed. But I would be getting connection errors if I tried to install anything using it. I have updated the CentOS version btw.

Comment: Well, if yum is configured, you could probably ask `yum` (in dry-run or test mode) what rpms it would like to download and the location of those rpms. Then you could download them manually. Not a RH user, so can't give details.